# Альтернатива action url & post - form

Tags: php, ajax

Подскажите, можно ли, например, при помощи curl'а выполнить запрос в стиле формы с последующей переадресацией ?
Ну т.е если есть форма, то там понятно все..вводим данные, метод POST и action на какой нибудь скрипт или ссылку.

Мне нужно заменить форму ajax'ом, где я посылаю данные на свой обработчик ($.ajax post url и т.п), который сформировал бы ссылку с POST параметрами и я мог бы ее вернуть для редиректа..
Дайте совет, как лучше поступить, ибо формой ну прям вообще никак.

```
      $post_data = array(
//      'wmid'=>$WMID,
        'LMI_PAYEE_PURSE'=>$LMI_PAYEE_PURSE,
        'LMI_PAYMENT_NO'=>$LMI_PAYMENT_NO,
        'LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT'=>$LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT,
        'LMI_PAYMENT_DESC'=>'ququmber',
        'LMI_SIM_MODE'=>'0',

        );

$url = 'https://merchant.webmoney.ru/lmi/payment_utf.asp';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
$output  = curl_exec ($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: дак как пишите, так и сделайте. в чем проблема-то?

Comment: проблема в том, что когда я формирую POST строку и возвращаю ее для редиректа - не работает. Вот и прошу помочь или показать, как правильно сформировать POST строку..

Comment: дак вы покажите, как вы это делаете

Comment: @teran добавил то, что имею на данный момент..уже многое повырезал..в итоге в $output возвращается ошибка от webmoney типа "Так делать нИзя". Я склоняюсь к тому, что я туплю и совершаю ошибку..подскажите, если так

Comment: из кода выше, видно только то, что вы отправляете запрос через curl. Покажите код, где вы возвращаете post ссылку на frontend